# SQL Server query to get the total for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2014

I have two tables `InvoiceLine` and `Discount`:

[image]

I need to get a result set which includes invoice Line items with the total (SUM) of discounts in the discount table like below:

[image]

How can I achieve this using only one query?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @InvoiceLine TABLE
    (
      InvoiceHeaderID INT ,
      InvoiceLineNo INT ,
      ProductCode VARCHAR(5) ,
      Price MONEY
    );

INSERT  INTO @InvoiceLine
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 'AB001', 1200 ),
        ( 2, 1, 'AC002', 1525 );


DECLARE @Discount TABLE
    (
      InvoiceHeaderID INT ,
      InvoiceLineNo INT ,
      DiscountCategory VARCHAR(10) ,
      discountValue MONEY
    );
INSERT  INTO @Discount
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 'SalesDisc', 120 ),
        ( 1, 1, 'FixedOffer', 100 ),
        ( 2, 1, 'SalesDisc', 152.50 );


SELECT  l.InvoiceHeaderID ,
        l.InvoiceLineNo ,
        l.ProductCode ,
        l.Price ,
        ISNULL(SUM(d.discountValue),0) [TotalDiscount]
FROM    @InvoiceLine l
        LEFT JOIN @Discount d ON d.InvoiceHeaderID = l.InvoiceHeaderID
                                 AND d.InvoiceLineNo = l.InvoiceLineNo
GROUP BY l.InvoiceHeaderID ,
        l.InvoiceLineNo ,
        l.ProductCode ,
        l.Price;
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Exactly, this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
A.InvoiceHeaderID, A.InvoiceLineNo, ProductCode, Price, SUM(DiscountValue) as TotDiscount
FROM
InvoiceLine A, Discount B
WHERE
A.InvoiceHeaderID = B.InvoiceHeaderID
AND A.InvoiceLineNo = B.InvoiceLineNo
GROUP BY
A.InvoiceHeaderID, A.InvoiceLineNo, ProductCode, Price
Order BY
A.InvoiceHeaderID, A.InvoiceLineNo
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    i.InvoiceHeaderId,
    i.InvoiceLineNo,
    i.ProductCode,
    i.Price,
    [TotDiscount]=isnull(d.TotDiscount)
from
    [InvoiceLine] i
left join
    [Discount] d on i.InvoiceHeaderId=d.InvoiceHeaderId and i.InvoiceLineNo=d.InvoiceLineNo
group by
    i.InvoiceHeaderId,
    i.InvoiceLineNo,
    i.ProductCode,
    i.Price
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
InvoiceLine .InvoiceHeaderID, InvoiceLine .InvoiceLineNo, ProductCode, Price, SUM(DiscountValue) as TotDiscount
FROM
InvoiceLine, Discount 
WHERE
InvoiceLine .InvoiceHeaderID = Discount .InvoiceHeaderID AND A.InvoiceLineNo = Discount .InvoiceLineNo
GROUP BY InvoiceLine .InvoiceHeaderID, InvoiceLine .InvoiceLineNo, ProductCode, Price
Order BY InvoiceLine .InvoiceHeaderID, InvoiceLine .InvoiceLineNo
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.